# TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured on array map

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I got:

> TypeError: Right side of assignment cannot be destructured

error when I try to get array object's proprieties in one function in React. Do you know guys how to resolve this error? 
The array have only one object

```
 costs (){
        return this.state.costs.map(({ rent, utilities, accounting, glass, contractor, gas}) => ({
        rent: rent || 0,
        utilities: utilities || 0,
        accounting: accounting || 0,
        glass: glass || 0,
        contractor: contractor || 0,
        gas: gas || 0,

    }))[0]
    }


render () {
        const { rent, utilities, accounting, glass, contractor, gas} = this.costs();
        console.log( rent, utilities, accounting, glass, contractor, gas)
        return (.........
```

Comment: `this.costs()` is a method , you need to use `const { rent, utilities, accounting, glass, contractor, gas} = this.state.costs;`

Comment: Can you log out what `this.state.costs` is with `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.costs,undefined,2))`? I think it's strange you map a whole array in `this.costs` and then only take the first item from that.

Comment: @HMR 
  {
    "rent": 120,
    "utilities": 200,
    "accounting": 230,
    "gas": 130,
    "contractor": 220,
    "glass": 230
  }

Comment: @HMR I have only one object in that array

Comment: If that is what it logs then you should get an error on `this.state.costs.map` because map is not a function on an object, map is an Array method and what you just posted is not an array. Can you please update the question with what it actually logged? Three is a method called [copy and paste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste)

Comment: Does the state change over time? I'm wondering if you have an initial state that is not in the same structure.